# 'I think IT unlikely that our team can win'. <--Is IT the object?

Tags: grammar, syntactic-analysis, subordinate-clauses, dummy-it

> We think it unlikely that our inexperienced team can win a single > game this season.

Is "it" the direct object? If it is, what is the function of the noun clause "that our inexperienced team can win a single game this season"? Is it connected to "it" in any way?

Thank you very much.

Comment: The clause supplies the declaration which fills the semantic slot created by **it** and what is declared is said to be "unlikely".   *That our inexperienced team can win a single game this season is unlikely (so we think).*

Comment: Can the noun clause be the direct object?

Comment: Some people think so, and some older grammars may say so, but there's good reason to say that "it unlikely that our inexperienced team can win a single game this season"        is complement" (not object) of "think".

Comment: *it* is an object and *[to be] unlikely that our inexperienced team can win a single* is an object complement.

Comment: _it_ refers to _the outcome that our team wins a game this season_.

Comment: @JohnGordon I wouldn't go along with what you say. In Extraposition the "it" is a dummy element serving the syntactic purpose of filling the subject or (as here) object position; the extraposed element doesn’t give the meaning (reference) of it" but serves simply as a semantic argument of the VP.

Answer (score 28):

This is an extraposition construction. In an extraposition construction, we use a meaningless dummy pronoun *it*  in a position where, in terms of meaning, we'd like to use a clause. The dummy pronoun fills that particular position and the clause we would semantically like to use there appears at the end of the sentence (i.e. at the end of the larger clause that the smaller clause appears in). We say that this smaller clause has been *extraposed*—which is because it appears outside of the body of the larger clause it belongs with.

The reasons for using an extraposition construction vary. Often in an extraposition construction, the extraposed clause has been moved from a position in which it is clunky or difficult to process - very often the subject position. In other cases it might be because using a clause in that position is actually ungrammatical. Consider the following examples:

1. [That she was there] is interesting.
2. **It** is interesting [that she was there].
3. *[That she stole the diamond] seems. (ungrammatical)
4. **It** seems [that she stole the diamond].

With examples (1-2), we can see that in (1), where the clause appears in the subject position, it is very clunky - but grammatical. In contrast, (3) is completely ungrammatical in English and the extraposition construction in (4) is obligatory. Notice that in the extraposition constructions, although we interpret the clause as being in the position where the word *it* appears, the word *it* is meaningless. It does not *refer to* the clause at the end of the sentence. This is not straightforwardly easy to see but has been shown absolutely decisively in papers such as Paul Postal and Geoff Pullum's (1988) [*Expletive noun phrases in subcategorized positions*](https://lel.ed.ac.uk/%7Egpullum/Postal-Pullum88.pdf).

**The Original Poster's example**

> 1. We think **it** unlikely [that our inexperienced team can win a single game this season].

This is what *The Cambridge grammar of the English language* (Huddleston & Pullum 2002: p. 963) calls a *complex transitive construction*. Here is their example sentence, where the bolding and brackets are mine:

> 2. I find **it** hardly surprising [that he tried to retract his statement].

In the construction above they state that the meaningless dummy pronoun *it* is the direct object of the word *find*, and that the clause that I have put in brackets is in ***extraposed object*** position. Note that the verb *find* could be substituted by the verb *think* in that example. And that although it would change the meaning, we could swap the adjective *unlikely* for the adjective *surprising*.

In short, the Original Poster is correct. The meaningless dummy pronoun *it* is indeed the direct object of the verb *think* in (1). It is connected with the clause *that ... this season*, in that it tells us where the extraposed clause belongs semantically in the larger sentence. However, the pronoun *it* doesn't actually *refer* to that clause.

---

**Appendix:**

Here is the relevant excerpt from Huddleston & Pullum:

> **The complex-transitive construction**
>
> [26]
>
> - i *I find it hardly surprising **that he tried to retract his statement***.
> - ii *They regard it as a discourtesy **that you didn't notify them earlier***.
>
> Example [i] may be compared with *I find his behaviour hardly surprising*, where the predicand of the predicative complement hardly surprising is an NP in object function. If the predicand is a content clause we normally need it as a dummy object, with the content clause in extraposed object position, as here. The content clause cannot itself occupy the position between verb and predicative complement, for a clausal complement cannot in general be followed within the VP by another complement; however, a version without the extrapositional it is possible if the content clause is preposed to prenuclear position:
>
> [27]
>
> - i *I find **that he tried to retract his statement** hardly surprising*.
> - ii ***That he tried to retract his statement** I find hardly surprising*.

---

**References**:

Huddleston, Rodney and Geoffrey K. Pullum (2002) *The Cambridge grammar of the English language*. Cambridge University Press.

Postal, Paul M. and Geoffrey K. Pullum (1988): Expletive noun phrases in subcategorized positions. *Linguistic Inquiry* **19**, 635–670.

Comment: +1. Any chance of having an electronic copy of  "Implications of English extraposed irrealis clauses"?

Comment: @user424874 I've substituted in the far more useful [*Expletive noun phrases in subcategorized positions*](http://www.lel.ed.ac.uk/~gpullum/Postal-Pullum88.pdf) from the same year. The "Implications" one is not widely available electronically - in fact hens teeth are easier to come by. I do have a copy, but would have to email it.

Comment: @Araucaria-Him I've finessed your link to avoid security errors in my web browser [[Edit pending approval](https://english.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/453994)]. I do know someone I could ask for hens' "teeth," so I think you're probably right. :-)

Comment: *the word* it *[...] does not refer to the clause at the end of the sentence.* - yes it does. Maybe not in 1988 in whatever dialect Postal and Pullum spoke, but in my dialect it does. P&P say for instance that "I haven't prepared my lecture, so I'll have to wing it" is grammatical but "I haven't prepared, so I'll have to wing my lecture" is ungrammatical. To me, both are fine. The paper covers much more ground than your answer and certainly there are cases where "it" refers to nothing. Maybe "It seems that she stole the diamond" is one such, but "It is interesting that she was there" isn't.

Comment: @benrg Interesting. There's two different "It's interesting that she wasn't there"s, of course, which can only be differentiated in writing by a comma: "It's interesting, that she wasn't there" and "It's interesting that she wasn't there". The first is what's sometimes called a right dislocation, where there's a pronoun in the body of the clause which refers to someone/thing, and then a fuller reference to that same thing again afterwards. There's not necessarily a pause between the two, but the rephrased reference to the same person/thing will come after the nuclear tone in the sentence.

Comment: @benrg To give a very different example of a right dislocation: "He's really cool, your Dad".  I'm absolutely with you on the "I'll have to wing my lecture". Don't know if it was different 35 years ago or not? (shrugs). Back to the extraposition/dislocation, one way to differentiate between a right dislocation with a clause and an extraposition is that the right dislocation needs a "that". I wonder if in your example of "It's interesting that she wasn't there" the *that* is omissible or not? (but still keeping "she wasn't there" in the same sentence and same intonational phrase/tune)

Comment: @Araucaria-Him You're right—I parsed it as a dislocation, and if I drop "that" then "it" no longer seems to refer to anything. I can't convince myself to parse the version with "that" that way, but it may just be me. I think you should mention this in the answer since the sentence in the question is ambiguous. The "wing it" example may be irrelevant. You said that P&P show decisively that "it" refers to nothing in your examples, but I don't know which part of the paper you're referring to.

Answer (score 1):

> *We think* [*it unlikely that our inexperienced team can win a single game*
> *this season*].

No, "it" is not an object.

It's the subject of the bracketed embedded subordinate content clause functioning as complement of "think".

Notes:

[1] "that and "is" can be added:

> *We think* [*that it is unlikely that our inexperienced team can win a*
> *single game this season*].

[2] within the bracketed content clause is the further subordinate content clause *that our* *inexperienced team can win a single game this season*, functioning as complement of "unlikely"

Comment: That's not what Huddleston and Pullum appear to say on p. 963, I don't think.

Comment: Is "it unlikely" (without a form of *to be*) a subordinate clause, or just a direct object + predicative complement?

Comment: But _it_ can be passivized _**It** is thought unlikely that our inexperienced team can win a single game this season_. Surely this should be enough to qualify it as an object. Are you arguing that a declarative content clause can have the predicator omitted under certain conditions? Further, if the content clause following _unlikely_ were not present, would your analysis change, and if so, why?